# Bootstrap modal with iframe not allowing vertical scrolling on iPhone only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-scrolling

I am bootstrap modal on a page with an iFrame, with form in an iframe which is large. I am not able to scroll this form
vertically on iPhone browsers. I cross checked same on android phone and i am able to scroll down. But with iphone
there seems to be some issue.

Not sure what could be the problem

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLoginForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog model-bookingform" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center" style="position:absolute; right:0px; z-index:999; padding:0px;">
        @*<h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Form</h4>*@
        <button type="button" class="close btn-model-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 z-depth-1-half bookingformiframe-w">
        <iframe id="iframex" class="embed-responsive-item" style="overflow:auto;" src="https://example.com/largeform"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

I even added additional css with no solution, when i try to scroll rather than scrolling the iframe content it seems to
scroll page

```
@media (max-width:800px) {
  #modalLoginForm {
    overflow: scroll;
    z-index: 999999 !important;
  }

  iframex {
    overflow: scroll !important;
    z-index: 9999999 !important;
  }
}

.modal {
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}

.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: auto !important;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be Safari scrolling problem. Try to add  `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` property to iframe's wrapper, like this:

```
.embed-responsive {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: I had tried this before it does not work?, i have spend hours to get this working with no luck

Comment: Please try this on iframe tag: `<iframe id="iframex" class="embed-responsive-item" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;" src="https://example.com/largeform"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix following worked, Issue seems to be with iPhone only as it works fine on other mobile devices

```
.embed-responsive-16by9 {
    padding-bottom: 0% !important;
    height:1100px !important;
}
```